# Front end field alignment in MVC Application

Tags: .net, html, css, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

So we have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application. The problem is, on our front end, a lot of fields don't like up with each other. I'd say with about 90-95% of the fields displayed to the user we are using HTML Helpers. We also mainly use the new ones released in MVC 2, the "for" helpers, for example, `Html.DropDownListFor`

Look at this picture:
[image]

These are both using the same HTML Helper, mentioned above. Here is the code for that specific picture:

```
    <td class="leftRightBorder">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResetDayComponent.ResetBusinessDayConvention, DropDownData.BusinessDayConventionList(), "", new { propertyName = "ResetDayComponent.ResetBusinessDayConvention", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Frequency</td>
    <td class="leftRightBorder">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FixedComponent.PaymentFrequency, DropDownData.FrequencyDropList(), "", new { propertyName = "FixedComponent.PaymentFrequency",  onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
    </td>
    <td />
    <td>Frequency</td>
    <td class="leftRightBorder">
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FloatingComponent.PaymentFrequency, DropDownData.FrequencyDropList(), "", new { propertyName = "FloatingComponent.PaymentFrequency", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
    </td>
```

The second frequency is the one you see, the other is in a table to the left of these two dropdowns.

How can I set a common length for dropdowns, text fields, etc. throughout the app so everything looks consistent and not messy?

Comment: You really should examine if your page layout needs to use tables.  Using <div> tags is much less of a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [cascading style sheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) to define global styles for HTML elements:

```
select, textarea, input[type=text] { width: 300px; }
```

or to style only within `.leftRightBorder`

```
.leftRightBorder select, 
.leftRightBorder textarea, 
.leftRightBorder input[type=text] 
{
    width: 300px; 
}
```